# How to find all the files created by GenerateTableFetch has been processed

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a flow where GenerateTableFetch takes inpute from splitJson which gives TableName, ColumnName as argument. At once multiple tables are passed as input to GenerateTableFetch and next ExecuteSql executes the query.

Now i want to trigger a new process when all the files for a table has been processed by the below processor (At the end there is PutFile).

How to find that all the files created for a Table has been processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need [NIFI-5601](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5601) to accomplish this, there is a patch currently under review at the time of this writing, I hope to get it into NiFi 1.9.0.

**EDIT**: Adding potential workarounds in the meantime

If you can use ListDatabaseTables instead of getting your table names from a JSON file, then you can set `Include Count` to `true`. Then you will get attributes for the table name and the count of its rows. Then you can divide the count by the value of the `Partition Size` in GTF and that will give you the number of fetches (let's call it `X`). Then add an attribute via UpdateAttribute called "parent" or something, and set it to `${UUID()}`. Keep these attributes in the flow files going into GTF and ExecuteScript, then you can use Wait/Notify to wait until `X` flow files are received (setting `Target Signal Count` to `${X}`) and using `${parent}` as the `Release Signal Identifier`.

If you can't use ListDatabaseTables, then you may be able to have ExecuteSQLRecord after your SplitJSON, you can execute something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table.name}`. If using ExecuteSQL, you may need a ConvertAvroToJSON, if using ExecuteSQLRecord use a JSONRecordSetWriter. Then you can extract the count from the flow file contents using EvaluateJsonPath.

Once you have the table name and the row count in attributes, you can continue with the flow I outlined above (i.e. determine the number of flow files that GTF will generate, etc.).

Comment: Hi Matt, Is there any way in the current release to achieve this?

Comment: Just updated my answer to include possible workaround(s).